Bluetooth Error on Startup
I have installed Ubuntu Server 24.04 in a VM (VMware Workstation 17) in an attempt to learn a bit about Linux.
When I start up the VM, I see the following:

From here, I can enter my logon credentials and everything seems to be work as expected. For a bit of context, I am a complete Linux noob. I tried to search the web using the error code and message but nothing useful (as far as I can tell) was returned. Either I am searching for the wrong thing or interpreting the results incorrectly.
Can someone point me in the direction of resolving this issue / explain a bit about what the cause is for educational purposes.

Not sure whether this ultimately makes a difference (other than the obvious), but I am not seeing this issue when creating the VM in Hyper-V. Perhaps this is simply an issue with VMware. I have only tried creating the VM in VMware and Hyper-V so I cannot speak to other tools such as Virtualbox.
